# Searching on a variable-defined field with ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

Here is the relevant code:

```
var field = String(querystring.parse(postData).field).toLowerCase();
var qryObj = {
"fields" : view_options,
"query":{
    "term" : { field : value} 
    }
};
```

The variable 'field' will be a string, like "number", "date", etc.  What I want to do is search the index only in the field that is defined in the variable 'field'.  This code works if I hardcode the string, like this:

```
"term" : { "number" : value}
```

So can someone shed some light on a way to only search a specific field using a predefined variable instead of a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use variables as keys in an [Object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). On the left of each `:`, identifiers themselves become the key's name rather than being evaluated as variables for their values.

```
console.log({ key: "value" });   // { key: 'value' }
console.log({ "key": "value" }); // { key: 'value' }
```

You'll have to build the `Object` first using [bracket member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), then apply it to the query object:

```
var term = {};
term[field] = value;

var qryObj = {
    fields: view_options,
    query: {
        term: term
    }
};
```

---

Update:

With ECMAScript 6, [Object literals do now support computed keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) using bracket notation for the key:

```
var qryObj = {
    fields: view_options,
    query: {
        term: {
            [field]: value
        }
    }
};
```